# SharpSNMP: Error running VB.NET code for snmpget

Tags: sharp-snmp

I am trying to run the snmpget code sample in VB.NET available at:
[https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/Samples/VB.NET/snmpget/](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/tree/master/Samples/VB.NET/snmpget)

When I try to run the code, I get the following exception:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5s9Z.png

The text on the exception indicates that the length of the string used to instantiate `ObjectIdentifier` is less than 2. However, this is not the case as seen in the watch window.

Could you let me know:

1. Any suggestions to fix this error. Am I not passing the command line args correctly?
2. Could you provide a sample command line argument string for SNMP v3?

Thank you for all the support!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough that you cannot pass "0", or any other string that contains a single number. A valid OID requires at least two portion, such as "0.0".

https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600001&referringTitle=KB

Command line tool usage can be found in [KB6000001](https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600001&referringTitle=KB) and you can find other documentation on CodePlex too,

https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Thanks. Could you let me know what what I need to put for the privacy method in the command line arg if I am using AES 128 instead of DES? Do I just specify AES? Where do I specify 128 if at all?